# kitchen converge failed on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: chef-infra, ubuntu-18.04, test-kitchen, kitchen-dokken

When I run "kitchen converge" kitchen I can't install chef and the following output comes out

```
    Installing chef
       installing with dpkg...
(Reading database ... 42662 files and directories currently installed.)
           Preparing to unpack .../cache/chef_16.1.16-1_amd64.deb ...
           Unpacking chef (16.1.16-1) ...
           dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
           dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
           dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/omnibus/cache/chef_16.1.16-1_amd64.deb (--install):
            cannot copy extracted data for './opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so' to '/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
           Errors were encountered while processing:
            /tmp/omnibus/cache/chef_16.1.16-1_amd64.deb
           Installation failed
           Version:
```

this is my kitchen file

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

  always_update_cookbooks: false


verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-18.04


suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[java::default]
    verifier:

    attributes:
```

but the installation works if I put platform ubuntu 14.04. Some idea? I am working on windows 10 home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have no issue with `ubuntu/bionic64` version `20200604.0.0`.

i suggest you to update the vagrant box that you are using. you can do that by listing the boxes

```sh
vagrant box list
```

then note the name of the box that you like to update, for instance `ubuntu/bionic64`, and update it

```sh
vagrant box update --box ubuntu/bionic64
```

once done, try `kitchen converge` again.

if you wish to use a different vagrant box (i use ubuntu official box), modify your kitchen file as follows

```yaml
driver:
  box: 'ubuntu/bionic64'
```

Comment: I tried as you said but kitchen by default runs bento / ubuntu-18.04 and convergence fails. The strange thing is that he cannot install chefs.

Comment: I modified the kitchen file as you said but now the kitchen create command fails. 

STDERR: Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

Answer (score 0):

The same this happened to me while I was working out of Ghana. It seems to be a problem with poor internet download of chef_16.1.16-1_amd64.deb (found out checksum fails).

The solution is to download the file manually (most likely with a download manager) and then copy it into

```
~/.kitchen/cache/
```

overwrite if the file already exists and run

```
kitchen converge
```

This should fix the issue.